# Não está retornando retornando o json

Tags: java, android, web-service, volley

Bom estou começando na área de android e ainda não sei muito a respeito e gostaria de ajuda com o seguinte código:

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lastedAnimeView);
    gridView.setAdapter(va);
    mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String lastedAnimesUrl = "http://10.0.0.13/anime/request/lastedAnimes.php";
    JsonObjectRequest jr = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, lastedAnimesUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
            parseJSON(response);
            va.notifyDataSetChanged();
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i(TAG, error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    mRequestQueue.add(jr);
}

private void parseJSON(JSONObject json){
    try {
        JSONArray items = json.getJSONArray("result");
        for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){

            JSONObject item = items.getJSONObject(i);
            NewsModel nm = new NewsModel();
            nm.setNome(item.optString("Nome"));
            URL urlGetImg = new URL(item.optString("Imagem"));
            HttpURLConnection conexao = (HttpURLConnection) urlGetImg.openConnection();
            InputStream inputImg = conexao.getInputStream();
            Bitmap insertImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputImg);
            nm.setImg(insertImg);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class NewsModel{
    private String nome;
    private Bitmap img;
    private String idAnime;

    void setNome(String nome){
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    void setImg(Bitmap img){
        this.img = img;
    }

    void setIdAnime(String IdAnime){
        this.idAnime = idAnime;
    }

    String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    Bitmap getImg(){
        return img;
    }

    String getId(){
        return idAnime;
    }
}

class VolleyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrNews.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return arrNews.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ViewHolder vh;
        if(view == null){
            vh = new ViewHolder();
            view = lf.inflate(R.layout.activity_item_grid_view, null);
            vh.showImg = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgItem);
            vh.showNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textItem);
        }else {
            vh = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        NewsModel nm = arrNews.get(i);
        vh.showNome.setText(nm.getNome());
        vh.showImg.setImageBitmap(nm.getImg());
        return view;
    }
    class ViewHolder{
        TextView showNome;
        ImageView showImg;
    }
}
```

Ele tem que retornar o os valores do json que está na minha webservice e colocar em uma GridView
JSON

```
{
"error": false,
"result": [
    {
        "Id": 33032,
        "Nome": "Bakumatsu - Episódio 05",
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/95110.jpg",
    },
    {
        "Id": 33022,
        "Nome": "Release the Spyce - Episódio 04",
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/95617.jpg",
    },
    {
        "Id": 33043,
        "Nome": "Zombieland Saga - Episódio 05",
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/94765.jpg",
    },
    {
        "Id": 33029,
        "Nome": "Merc Storia: Mukiryoku no Shounen to Bin no Naka no Shoujo 
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/95576.jpg",
    },
    {
        "Id": 33015,
        "Nome": "Tokyo Ghoul:re 2nd Season - Episódio 04",
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/93889.jpg",
    },
    {
        "Id": 32879,
        "Nome": "Captain Tsubasa (2018) – Episódio 31",
        "Imagem": "http://10.0.0.13/animes/img-anime/91260.jpg",
    }
```